# Pass Context or Activity to adapter using Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I inject an Adapter using Dagger 2 without context and it is working, but I am not able to do when I am passing context parameter. Error is coming like this

```
error: android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

Dagger Component

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = MainFragmentModule.class)
public interface MainFragmentComponent {

    void inject(MainFragment mainFragment);

    @ActivityContext
    Context provideContext();
}
```

Fragment Module

```
@Module
public class MainFragmentModule {

    private MainFragmentContract.View mView;
    private Activity mActivity;
    Context mContext;

    MainFragmentModule(MainFragmentContract.View view, Context context) {
        mView = view;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Provides
    MainFragmentContract.View providesView() {
        return mView;
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityContext
    Context provideContext() {
        return mContext;
    }


}
```

Adapter

```
  @Inject
    public ConversationAdapter(MainFragmentPresenter mainPresenter, Context context) {
        mMainFragmentPresenter = mainPresenter;
        mContext =context;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the (Activity?) code where the Adapter is used? Including Dagger initialization in this class.

Comment: I am not able to add Fragment code ... error in when i am clicking on save.

Comment: DaggerMainFragmentComponent.builder().applicationComponent(((QTConnectApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getComponent())
                .mainFragmentModule(new MainFragmentModule(this, getContext()))
                .build().inject(this);

Comment: This above code i have used in onCreateView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have told dagger, that you are providing a specific context:

```
@ActivityContext
Context provideContext();
```

And then you are asking dagger to inject your adapter with another type of context - one, which is not annotated with `@ActivityContext`.

Instead, you should explicitly define, that you are willing to provide exactly that type of context:

```
    @Inject
    public ConversationAdapter(..., @ActivityContext Context context) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks .. its done , Please help me if  want to pass Activity instead of context.